# C++ detecting const int passed into function

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a function that we use to enforce type matches when setting into a buffer:

```
void SetUInt8(size_checker<uint8_t> val)
{
     // make some static checks
}
```

usually, it is invoked like this:

```
// compile error, since you might mean to call the SetUInt() function
int myvar = 10;
SetUInt8(myvar);      

// works fine
int8_t myvar = 1;
SetUInt8(myvar);
```

This call causes a warning because the `30` is interpreted as an `int`:

```
SetUInt8(30);
```

But I really want this to be OK since 30 < 256.  Ideally, I would like the invocation not to have to change, but I have come up with the following:

```
template<size_t T>
void SetUInt8()
{
    ASSERT(T < 256);
    // do other stuff
}
```

Which of course would be used like:

```
SetUInt8<30>();
```

Alternatively, I can cast when calling the function:

```
SetUInt8(uint8_t(30U));
```

Is there another way around the issue of 30 being converted to an int, or detecting its actual value if its a compile time constant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking at compile time if specified value is in a range of a type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5556466/636019)

Comment: @ildjarn: That range-checks a non-type template argument; this is certainly different (and harder).

Comment: @MSalter : I don't see why an overload can't be provided for literals (which are what's causing the warnings), which does the range check then delegates its actual work to the existing overload...

Comment: @ildjarn: C++ doesn't have overloading on literals.

Comment: @MSalters : I meant `SetUInt8<30>();` vs. `SetUInt8(30);` (sorry, thought this was obvious).

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, that's technically not an overload. If you stick to the `SetUInt8(30);` call syntax, the question would require a real overload of `SetUInt8` that's selected because the argument (`30U`) is a literal. Well, such overloading just doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: @MSalters : I'm not suggesting sticking to the `SetUInt8(30);` call syntax, I'm suggesting having a different syntax for literals.

Comment: Certainly a different syntax is possible (as I mention).  My goal is to avoid that.  Code would be much cleaner if all calls could be `SetUInt8(blah)`.  Looks like I may have to give up on my hopes....

Answer (score 2):

The best thought I have is a template, static-asserted function that `static_cast`s for you:

```
template<size_t size>
void SetUInt8()
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(size < 256);
    SetUInt8(static_cast<uint8_t>(size));
}
```

Call it like you did: `SetUInt8<50>();`

Since it should hopefully always be inlined there's no performance overhead and it does compile-time range checking. Better would be if the compiler were smart enough to not warn when the value clearly fits in the range of the smaller type.